# Can we have separate homepage sections for recent badges of different grades?

Tags: feature-request, badges, homepage

Rather than having a single sidebar box for the most recent 18 badges (with SO displaying only silver and gold badges), sites should have one each for bronze, silver and gold badges.  If the dedication of a bit more real estate is seen as pleasing, I'd say display ten of each.

This gives all badges a chance to hit the homepage, and we no longer have the more significant badges being quickly chased off by their inferiors (especially gold badges, which deserve to hold a place of honor for a bit longer than they do on any of the sites).